# Table images don't appear

Tags: html, css, html-table

HTML code:

```
<div class="produtos2">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="4" CELLSPACING="80">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="images/h_calcas/ola.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                <br />
                Caption text centered under the image.
            </td>

            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="images/h_calcas/ola1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                <br />
                Caption text centered under the image.
            </td>

            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="images/h_calcas/ola2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                <br />
                Caption text centered under the image.
            </td>

            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <img src="images/h_calcas/ola3.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                <br />
                Caption text centered under the image.

            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <img src="images/h_calcas/ola4.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                    <br />
                    Caption text centered under the image.
                </td>

                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <img src="images/h_calcas/ola5.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                    <br />
                    Caption text centered under the image.
                </td>

                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <img src="images/h_calcas/ola6.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                    <br />
                    Caption text centered under the image.
                </td>

                <td align="center" valign="center">
                    <img src="images/h_calcas/ola7.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="description here" />
                    <br />
                    Caption text centered under the image.</td> </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.produtos2{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: gray;
}

table{
    margin: auto;
}    

table img{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The folder of the html file is in "www" and in it there is the folder "images" with the images inside. But the images never appear. I thought it could be something about the display so I tried `display:block;` and `display:inline-block;` but it still didn't work.

Folder:

[image]

Comment: it's not related to table. Check your image path. To get help from us. show us your folder structure.

Comment: whats the full url of your site? the fiddle can't work without it but your actual web page should work if you specify the paths correctly

Comment: you have a problem with your paths. here's a fiddle with placeholder images: https://jsfiddle.net/no7zco1f/1/

Comment: I'll just say: image**n**s

Comment: Thank you! @LordNeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path incorrect. Image**n**s by @LordNeo